# I want to create a menu that shows 1.Client ID, 2.Property details,3.Exit

Tags: c

```
`#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{

  char L,F,H;
  float length,breadth,CID,Aoc;/*Pte*/
  float Cost_per_sqft,Total_cost, GST;
  int dicnt,age,ch;
  char Pte;
    
  printf("Enter the Client ID\n");
  scanf("%f", &CID);
  printf("Enter the age of client\n");
  scanf("%d", &age);
  if (age >=60)
  {
      printf("The client is eligible for a discount\n");
  }  
     else if (age<60)
     {
         printf("The client is not eligible for a discount\n");
     }
 { printf("Select Porperty type\nF=Flat\nL=Land\nH=House\n");
  scanf(" %c", &Pte);
  printf("Enter length\n");
  scanf("%f", &length);
  printf("Enter breadth\n");
  scanf("%f", &breadth);
if (Pte=F)
{ 
    Cost_per_sqft = 5000.0;
    printf("Cost per sqft = %f\n", Cost_per_sqft);
}
else if (Pte=L)
{
    Cost_per_sqft = 6000.0;
    printf("Cost per sqft = %f\n", Cost_per_sqft);
}
    else if (Pte=H);
    {
        Cost_per_sqft = 9000.0;
        printf("Cost per sqft = %f\n", Cost_per_sqft);
    }
    
  printf("Please select the menu option\n");
  printf("1.Client ID\n");
  printf("2.Property details\n");
  printf("3.Exit\n");
  scanf("%d", &ch);
  switch(ch)
  {
    case 1:
        printf("Client ID = %f\n", CID);
        printf("Age of client = %d", age);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Property type = %c\n", Pte);
        printf("Cost per square feet = %f\n", Cost_per_sqft);
        Total_cost = (length*breadth*Cost_per_sqft); 
        printf("Total cost = %f", Total_cost);
        break;
    case 3:
        ;//add content
        break;          
    
  }
    
}
    
}
```

`[image: Output]

The program is taking value of cost per sqft of House which is 9000, even if I enter Flat or Land variables. another problem is the total cost of the property. instead of taking the desired property types cost per sqft, I believe its multiplying cost per sqft for all values F,L,H. and in the property details menu, the type of property doesn't show either.

Comment: I wonder whether there are some warnings from your compiler regarding assignment in condition or some stray `;` after `if`. If not, you should turn on warnings. For GCC you can do this using `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: I would suggest to apply consistent indentation to your code. Different indentation for same level of indentation confuses readers.

Comment: Finally, you should not post text as images. You can copy&paste plain text into the question. No need to add graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use commenting on your code it'll be easy to find the bug, even for you.

```
 else if (Pte=H);
{
    Cost_per_sqft = 9000.0;
    printf("Cost per sqft = %f\n", Cost_per_sqft);
}
```

Try removing the termination operator (';') from the else if statement.

Also use '==' instead of '=' in conditional statements.
eg.
in `if (Pte=F)` use `if (Pte=='F')` instead

That should just help you make your code run.